# iOS draggable subview

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Facing some difficulties implementing draggable View. using monotouch, but I dont' think it is language-specific...
the problem details:
I have a View that handles TouchesBegan, TouchesMove and reposition itself (by changing Frame property). That work perfect!
once I'm adding ScrollView with disabled scrolling and paging, any touches made on the scrollview are not getting to the View that has to move. Setting UserInteraction to NO fixes moving problem, but none of the controls hosted inside the scroller responds any touch.

Any idea on how to have ScrollView and allow it's superview to receive all the touches when there's no scrolling events available?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the touch to the subViews, this category for `UIScrollView` will do the job:

```
@implementation UIScrollView (FixedApi)

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    NSLog(@"touch view = %@", [[touch view].class description]);
    if ([[[touch view].class description] isEqualToString:@"UITableView"]) {
        //You have touched a UITableView
    } else if ([[[touch view].class description] isEqualToString:@"UIView"]) {
        //You have touched a UIView
    } else {
         //Ignore the category and return the touch to the UIScrollView.
         [self.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; // or 1 nextResponder, depends
         [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ( !self.dragging ) [self.nextResponder.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the subview using PanGesture Action...

```
-(void)panGRAction {

  if (panGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    NSLog(@"touch view = %@", [[touch view].class description]);
    if ([[[touch view].class description] isEqualToString:@"UITableView"]) {
        //You have touched a UITableView
    } else if ([[[touch view].class description] isEqualToString:@"UIView"]) {
        //You have touched a UIView
    } else {
         //Ignore the category and return the touch to the UIScrollView.
         [self.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; // or 1 nextResponder, depends
         [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }

    } else if (panGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
if ( !self.dragging ) [self.nextResponder.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

}
```